# Creating an FTP server with user isolation

Tags: ftp, user-accounts, iis

I created an FTP site with IIS but when I try to set up user isolation (user name physical directory), I am not able to connect anymore and the anonymous authentication doesn't work anymore.  The login page says:

> "Could not login to the FTP server with the user name and password specified."

Ultimately, I would like to be able to set a directory for each user so that I don't need to host multiple servers.

I followed [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/publish/using-the-ftp-service/configuring-ftp-user-isolation-in-iis-7) but it did not work out for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I attach a few pictures to explain my set up:

IIS setup:
[image: IIS]

Physical setup:
[image: Contents]

(the folder "FTP" being the root folder)

User isolation settings:
[image: User isolation]

Comment: The article you linked must work, if you followed it correctly. You must give us very detailed information if you wish us to spot the mistake.